# How to create a filter to select items from two distinct lists and show in a view

Tags: web-part, cascading

I have two lists L1 (master) and L2 (slave) - for 1 item in L1 i have N items in L2 - joined with an Id (L2 has N items with additional info for the same Id - N persons associated to the master information).

I wish to create a View that shows L1 items AND the L2 related items (I have used a "related web part").

But this view should only show the L1 items that are related to the L2 items, that have a Person column identical to the user (Me). Its a query on two tables.
I have created the view with both lists, but how can I create this filter? By using a content query web part?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a lookup column yet?

What you describe is called 'cascading columns' - it's a bit fiddly to configure at first, [have a look at this MS link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39842.cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365.aspx).